# MVC .net for restful api

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm more acquainted with Java technologies and i'm running a project where i need to use the .Net framework for the backend. The goal of the project is to to expose a public api handling any request type PUT, POST, GET, DELETE. The payload will only be in JSON. The backend will be interacting with a database and third party libraries also written in .Net.

What are the technologies in .Net that are best suited for this. Is it Asp.Net with C#. Are there other framework people would recommend (Spring.Net for instance. Also There seems to be different version of .Net 3 & 4. Are all the versions equally valid for this type of project.

Finally what are the tools people use to develop, test unit and do integration test in the .Net environment.

Thank you
ken

Comment: http://www.servicestack.net/ - stable, good documentation and test coverage with examples of tests/frameworks to use to test your api. "A fast, unified and integrated replacement for WCF, WebAPI and MVC"

Comment: regarding the C# detail, if you're acquainted with Java, then C# is the logical choice since the 2 languages are very similar syntactically (as opposed to the other .NET core programming language: VB)

Comment: @MohammadSepahvand `the 2 languages are very similar syntactically` I disagree. think of anonymous classes/lambdas/query syntax etc. But the most important difference is the *ecosystem*, tools/libraries/coding styles etc.

Comment: [Java and C# Comparison](http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/java_csharp_comparison.html)

Comment: @MohammadSepahvand I think your c# knowledge is at least 6 years back. Just follow the `C#` tag on SO and see the difference.

Comment: @MohammadSepahvand Anything near in Java to this: `var list = from i in new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 } where i % 2 == 0 select "@" + i;` ?

Comment: @I4V You're correct but I think you misinterpreted my original post. C# 10 years ago or now doesn't change the fundamental _Syntactic_ structure of the language. Yes there have been numerous additions since it's inception but syntax doesn't change. True, The underlying structure and ecosystem of the 2 langues couldn't be more different (I'm never claimed otherwise) but the key word in my original post was _syntactically_. I learnt to program with Java and when I moved to .NET I found that I was coding C# instinctively. Btw, I started C# 3 years ago only so my c# knowledge cant be 6 years old;)

Comment: @I4V the `var keyword` and dynamic objects in general were only introduced to C# a couple years ago, and features like LINQ about 5 years ago but even then what impact do they have on the syntax governing the language? As I said, I never claimed that the features of the languages are similar, I said _Syntax_, and I stand by that.

Comment: @MohammadSepahvand So do you think a java programmer can port a c# function( think of a more complex example than I posted) to Java easily without knowing c#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET Web API allows you to create RESTful services and work with JSON data. Normal ASP.NET MVC also allows you to send JSON between your client and server, but Web API is the future. You could use normal ASP.NET (web forms) or ASP.NET MVC, MVC allows you to have a better organisation of your presentation logic and is just awesome. When you use Web API along with ASP.NET MVC, web API will be in charge of dealing with your data, and your asp.net MVC will be in charge of serving up your views. There are tonnes of material out there on ASP.NET MVC and Web API, so I won't bother posting any here. Finally, if you want your application to be more interactive and are focusing on good UX, then you could integrate as much AJAX as possible into your apps and even better make use of javascript frameworks such as knockout to create a highly responsive UI. Here is a good write up on using [Web API with Knockout.js](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amar/archive/2012/12/12/hello-world-with-knockout-js-and-asp-net-mvc-4.aspx). Also [a must read book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pro-NET-Edition-Professional-Apress/dp/1430242361) for aspiring asp.net MVC developers. The book covers unit testing with Visual Studio and Moq and Dependency Injection with Ninject briefly but well, you could unit test your javascript with [Qunit](http://qunitjs.com/), though it has nothing to do with .NET specifically.

Comment: Any chance you've done continuous integration, what did you use for ? In Java world, i used Hudson. Thx

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [WebAPI](http://www.asp.net/web-api) for building RESTful services, along with ASP.NET MVC 4 and C#. I would recommend Visual Studio 2012 and .NET Framework 4.5 if you are able to use these.

There are a variety of test frameworks in the .NET space (including MSTest, NUnit, and xUnit) and isolation frameworks such as Moq.

Comment: Why do you recommend Visual Studio 2012 and .Net 4.5 ? is there a substantial gain using these two comparing to older versions ?